# update multiple values in specific column in PostgreSQL 10.11

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join

In SQLYOG following code working fine but how i use this code in PostgreSQL 10.11
I have bulk data to do the same here is some example of my data

My table structure :-

```
CREATE TABLE shg_members (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `shg_id` INTEGER,
  `member_name` VARCHAR(14),
  `leadership_status` VARCHAR(9),
  `other_education` VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO shg_members
  (`id`, `shg_id`, `member_name`, `leadership_status`, `other_education`)
VALUES
  ('26', '18579', 'SARABJET KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('27', '18579', 'KULADIP KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('28', '18579', 'PARVINDER KAUR', 'President', NULL),
  ('29', '18579', 'KAMALJIT KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('30', '18579', 'JASPREET KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('31', '18579', 'LAJVANTI', 'President', NULL),
  ('32', '18579', 'RANJEET KAUR', 'President', NULL),
  ('33', '18579', 'GURPRIT KOUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('34', '18579', 'MANJEET KOUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('35', '18579', 'KULVINDER KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('36', '18579', 'KAMAL KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('37', '18579', 'SARJEET KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('38', '18580', 'KASHMIR KAUR', NULL, NULL),
  ('39', '18580', 'KIRANDEEP KOUR', 'President', NULL),
  ('40', '18580', 'SUKHDEEP KAUR', 'President', NULL),
  ('41', '18580', 'AMARJEET KAUR', 'President', NULL);
```

with using given query

```
UPDATE shg_members s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shg_id ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM shg_members
  WHERE shg_id IN (18579, 18580)
) t ON t.id = s.id
SET s.leadership_status = CASE t.rn
  WHEN 1 THEN 'President'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Secretary'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Treasurer'
  ELSE 'Member'
END
```

**Result**

```
> id | shg_id | member_name    | leadership_status | other_education
> -: | -----: | :------------- | :---------------- | :--------------
> 26 |  18579 | SARABJET KAUR  | President         | null          
> 27 |  18579 | KULADIP KAUR   | Secretary         | null          
> 28 |  18579 | PARVINDER KAUR | Treasurer         | null          
> 29 |  18579 | KAMALJIT KAUR  | Member            | null          
> 30 |  18579 | JASPREET KAUR  | Member            | null          
> 31 |  18579 | LAJVANTI       | Member            | null          
> 32 |  18579 | RANJEET KAUR   | Member            | null          
> 33 |  18579 | GURPRIT KOUR   | Member            | null          
> 34 |  18579 | MANJEET KOUR   | Member            | null          
> 35 |  18579 | KULVINDER KAUR | Member            | null          
> 36 |  18579 | KAMAL KAUR     | Member            | null          
> 37 |  18579 | SARJEET KAUR   | Member            | null          
> 38 |  18580 | KASHMIR KAUR   | President         | null          
> 39 |  18580 | KIRANDEEP KOUR | Secretary         | null          
> 40 |  18580 | SUKHDEEP KAUR  | Treasurer         | null          
> 41 |  18580 | AMARJEET KAUR  | Member            | null
```

but now in PostgreSQL 10.11 how i get the same output

Answer (score 2):

Postgres, as many other databases actually, implements the update/join syntax with a `FROM` clause. You could phrase this as:

```
UPDATE shg_members s
SET leadership_status = CASE t.rn
  WHEN 1 THEN 'President'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Secretary'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Treasurer'
  ELSE 'Member'
END 
FROM (
  SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shg_id ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM shg_members s
  WHERE shg_id IN (18579, 18580)
) t 
WHERE t.id = s.id
```

Comment: code working but it update all as member first 3 condition could not execute

Comment: @DeveshSharma: your comment is unclear to me. Here is a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bcd264bab1b216b32cb64f1144fa2579. This does produce the result that you want for your sample data.